# stop a thread in a function from another function

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Hello I would like to stop a thread that is running but I have to stop it from a function
Here is my code

```
import os
import time
import threading

def run():
    while True:
        print("ok")
        time.sleep(1)
        global stop
        if stop:
            print("stopped")
            break

def stopper():
    stop = True
    t1.join()
    print("done")


stop = False
t1 = threading.Thread(target=run)
t1.start()
time.sleep(4)
stopper()
```

I am forced to stop it from the stopper function and can't do it like that even if in this case it would work,My objective is to activate the stopper function from a tkinter button

```
time.sleep(4)
stop = True
t1.join()
print("done")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `global` declaration in your `stopper` function.

```
def stopper():
    global stop
    stop = True
    t1.join()
    print("done")
```

Will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put

```
global stop
```

into your `stopper()` function as well. Otherwise the function will not set the global `stop` but just a local variable with that name.

Answer (score 0):

how is with mp.Manager and ctypes, without global declaration

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import ctypes
import os
import time
import threading

def tunnel_signal():
    manager = mp.Manager()
    return manager.Value(ctypes.c_char_p, False)


def run(stop_signal):
    while True:
        print("ok")
        if stop_signal.value:
           break


def stopper():
    stop = True
    t1.join()
    print("done")


stop_thread = tunnel_signal()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(signal,))
t1.start()
time.sleep(4)
stop_thread.value = True
```